# "to not do that" or "not to do that"

Tags: word-order, negation

I'm saying

> How many times I asked you not to do that?

or

> How many times I asked you to not do that?

which one is correct please?

Answer (score 6):

Neither is completely correct: you can use

> How many times have I asked you not to do that?

or

> How many times have I asked you to not do that?

Notice how the word "I" is capitalised in English. This is always the case.

The word "have" is required as an auxiliary verb to form the present perfect with the past participle "asked" for it to make sense in those sentences.

Both "not to do" and "to not do" are correct.

Comment: With "Asked" vs. "Have asked," you might wish to note that the difference is [present perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_perfect#English) vs. [simple past](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_past): see also [this ELL question](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31882/37589).

Comment: @LMS Thank you. I have removed the unnecessary complication.

Answer (score 4):

> How many times did I ask you not to do that?
>
> How many times did I ask you to not do that?

The first sentence, in which we keep to and the infinitive do together, is more usual and idiomatic than the second sentence, in which we have a split infinitive. Many people think that a sentence with a split imfinitive
is not correct, but it's becoming generally acceptable.

Comment: Would it be incorrect to split the infinitive in "Didn't I ask you to not ever do that again!" instead of saying "Didn't I ask you never to do that again!"?

Comment: @Rompey - Unless it is awkward to do so, in most cases, and particularly in formal writing, you should probably try to avoid splitting infinitives. While there is no _rule_ prohibiting it, to many readers it will "feel" wrong. If your objective is to convey your thoughts, why add anything that might distract your audience?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference can really be seen when you say the phrase.

> How many times have I asked you **NOT** to do that?

vs.

> How many times have I asked you to **NOT** do that?

The emphasis is always put on "not".

Comment: ... but you still do not explain the diference...