# The government has declared/declared a state of emergency. (present perfect vs. past)

Tags: tense, present-tense

> The government has declared a state of emergency.

> The government declared a state of emergency.

Is there any difference between the two sentences?

Comment: The first one means that there is a state of emergency _now_. The second could refer to an event in history, not necessarily recent.

Comment: @KateBunting You could write an answer with your good comment.

Comment: Actually, I nearly voted to close your question as a duplicate of [this one](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/31882/simple-past-vs-present-perfect?rq=1), but the accepted answer to it isn't a very good one.